# jq Cannot index string with string "value"

Tags: jq

I have the short jq filter below which works perfectly:

```
cat data.tmp2 | ./jq-linux64-1.5 -r '.issues[].fields.customfield_10025 | if .value != null then (.value + "," + .child.value ) else "" end'
```

It produces exactly what I need, if the field is empty it returns "" if the field is not empty it uses the value of the field and concatenates a comma and a child value.
However when I move my filter in a larger filter seen below, I get an error: Cannot index string with string "value"

This is the longer filter that fails:

```
cat data.tmp2 | ./jq-linux64-1.5 -r '.issues | map([.key,.fields.project.name,.fields.parent.key,.fields.issuetype.name,.fields.status.name,.fields.priority.name,.fields.resolution.name,.fields.assignee.name,.fields.reporter.name,.fields.created,.fields.updated,.fields.resolutiondate,.fields.summary,(.fields.components | (map(.name?) | join (","))),(.fields.fixVersions | (map(.name?) | join (","))),.fields.customfield_10025 | if .value != null then (.value + "," + .child.value ) else "" end,.fields.customfield_10201] | join ("---"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting parentheses around the expression:

```
.fields.customfield_10025 | if .value != null then (.value + "," + .child.value ) else "" end
```

That is, `[1,2 | type]` is parsed as `[(1,2) | type]`, not `[1, (2|type)]`.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. Before I posted the question I had tried to use parantheses after the pipe, but didn't work... This did the trick though.